# T-SQL Query Help Pt. II

Tags: t-sql

The last query I need help with is for a specific reservation show the tentative cost the guest will have to pay.

Now this is a bit more complicated because there are two costs, one is the cost for the duration of their stay and the other is for another invoice they get billed to them from another invoice (which is for things such as dining during their stay).

The guest reservation table has the following columns with data:

```
(confirm_no, agent_id, g_name, g_phone)
```

The reservation table has the following columns with data:

```
(confirm_no, credit_card_no, res_checkin_date, res_checkout_date, 
 default_villa_type, price_plan)
```

The invoice table has the following columns with data:

```
(inv_no, inv_date, inv_amount, confirm_no).
```

The price plan table has the following columns with data:

```
(price_plan, rate, default_villa_type, bed_type)
```

So I need to somehow list the guests name with their total amount due which will be the `((res_checkout_date-res_checkin_date) * rate) + inv_amount` coming from the reservation table, price table and invoice table respectively (and the guest name from the guest reservation table which is linked through the confirm_no).

It seems complicated and I'm not even sure where to begin?

EDIT:

The guest reservation table looks like:

http://img535.imageshack.us/i/guestreservation.jpg/

The reservation table looks like:

http://img857.imageshack.us/i/reservation.jpg/

The invoice table has NOTHING in it currently.

The price plan table looks like:

I can't post more than too links but it's the same as the above with the name "priceplan.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might get you going in the right direction

```
select
  g.g_name, 
  datediff(d, r.res_checkin_date, r.res_checkout_date)*p.rate+coalesce(i.inv_amount, 0) as Amount
from reservation as r  
  inner join priceplan as p
    on r.price_plan = p.price_plan
  inner join guest_reservation as g
    on r.confirm_no = g.confirm_no
  left outer join invoice as i
    on r.confirm_no = i.confirm_no
```

Comment: With yours I get an error message stating: "Invalid column name 'confirm_no'."

Which especially confuses me?

Comment: @Jon – Edited question. I used table name Guest when it should be guest_reservation (or something like that?)

Comment: So now it works without errors however NO results returned only a g_name column and a "no column name" column and no results in them? 

Same as the datediff example someone else posted above.

Comment: @Jon – Updated answer to take care of the case where a guest does not have a row in Invoice table.

Comment: @Jon – http://stackoverflow.com/faq "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community."

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an INNER JOIN on the four tables and do your calculation:

Like this (untested):

```
select 
  GuestReservationTable.g_name, ((ReservationTable.res_checkout_date-ReservationTable.res_checkin_date) * PricePlanTable.rate) + InvoiceTable.inv_amount
from
  GuestReservationTable
  inner join ReservationTable on GuestReservationTable.confirm_no = ReservationTable.confirm_no
  inner join InvoiceTable on InvoiceTable .confirm_no = ReservationTable.confirm_no
  inner join PricePlanTable on PricePlanTable.price_plan = ReservationTable.PricePlan
```

Comment: When I tried this:

select 
  guest_reservation.g_name, ((reservation.res_checkout_date-reservation.res_checkin_date) * price_plan.rate) + invoice.inv_amount
from
  guest_reservation
  inner join reservation on  guest_reservation.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no
  inner join invoice on invoice.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no
  inner join price_plan on price_plan.price_plan = reservation.price_plan

I got the following error: "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to money is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATEDIFF to calculate the number of days and then use a join to get the values from each of the tables. The invoice table might not have a related row for the guest so it needs to be an outer join. The outer join means that inv_amount could be null so you need to check for that with ISNULL.

```
SELECT gr.guest_name, (DATEDIFF(d, r.res_checkout_date, r.res_checkin_date) * pp.rate ) + ISNULL(i.inv_amount, 0)
FROM guest_reservation gr LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice i ON gr.confirm_no = i.confirm_no
JOIN reservation r ON gr.confirm_no = r.confirm_no
JOIN price_plan pp ON r.price_plan = pp.price_plan
```

ISNULL at msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx
DateDiff help at msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: When I tried your query:

SELECT guest_reservation.g_name, (DATEDIFF(d, reservation.res_checkout_date, reservation.res_checkin_date) * price_plan.rate ) + invoice.inv_amount
FROM guest_reservation JOIN invoice ON guest_reservation.confirm_no = invoice.confirm_no
JOIN reservation ON guest_reservation.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no
JOIN price_plan ON reservation.price_plan = price_plan.price_plan

I had NO errors however NO results returned only a g_name column and a "no column name" column and no results in them?

Comment: And if I used yours strict copy and paste I got either an "ambiguous column" error for the price.plan and if I changed it to price_plan.price_plan I got a "The multi-part identifier "pric_plan.price_plan" could not be bound." error?

Comment: The query was missing the pp table identifier in the final join. I have edited the sql.

Comment: Do all of the tables have rows for a guest? Looking at it again, I guess the invoice table could have no rows for a guest if they didn't hit the minibar. You should be able to break down the query and see what gives results. For example, just get the days the guest stayed, then join it with the price_plan table and calculate the price.

Comment: The invoice table currently has no data in it, would that result in providing no values or would it simply count that as zero and still provide a number total for the guest?

And not all the tables have a guest column, they have the columns I provided above exactly, nothing more.

Comment: If the invoice table has no row for the guest you you need to use an outer join. I have updated the example.